# Объединить два объекта в один

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть два объекта

Первый `win = {vasya:2,petya:1,kolya:3}`
Второй `loss = {kolya:1,vasya:2,petya:4}`

Как объединить в объект по следующему принципу

```
{
  vasya: {
    win: 2,
    loss: 2
  },
  petya: {
    win: 1,
    loss: 4
  },
  kolya: {
    win: 3,
    loss: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: это объекты,а не массивы

Comment: у Вас здесь нет массивов.Обновите вопрос с примером требуемого результата

Comment: @ddeadlink требуемый результат приведен в вопросе

Comment: Массивы с данными, я просто скопировал из консоли

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const win = {
  vasya: 2,
  petya: 1,
  kolya: 3
}
const loss = {
  kolya: 1,
  vasya: 2,
  petya: 4
}
let result = {}

Object.keys(win).forEach(key => {
  result = {
    ...result,
    [key]: {
      ...result[key],
      win: win[key]
    }
  }
})

Object.keys(loss).forEach(key => {
  result = {
    ...result,
    [key]: {
      ...result[key],
      loss: loss[key]
    }
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: прикольно, а можете объяснить что здесь делает оператор `...`?

Comment: nvm, разобрался. крутая штука, но читабильность такого кода это просто шок) хотя, возможно, дело привычки

Answer (score 4):

как вариант, но мне не нравится с `each`

```js
var win  = { vasya: 2, petya: 1, kolya: 3};
var loss = { kolya: 1, vasya: 2, petya: 4};

var w = {},l = {};
$.each(win, function(k,v){ w[k] = { win: v }; });
$.each(loss, function(k,v) { l[k] = { loss: v }; });

// или
//var cb = function(o, x){ return function(k,v){ o[k] = {[x]: v}} };
//$.each(win, cb(w, 'win'));
//$.each(loss, cb(l, 'loss'));

var result =  $.extend(true, {}, w,l);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = {}
res.forEach = function(handler){ for(var k in this){ if(typeof this[k] != 'function')handler(k, this[k]) }}
win.forEach((k, v)=>{ res[k] = res[k] || { win: 0, loss: 0 }; res[k].win += v; })
loss.forEach((k, v)=>{ res[k] = res[k] || { win: 0, loss: 0 }; res[k].loss += v; })
```

Comment: `forEach` над обьектом, серьезно ? Обновите ответ используя `Object.keys / Objects.values / Object.entries / for..in`  на Ваше усмотрение

Comment: Да, постоянно забываю что его нету из коробки :-)

Comment: дак и заменили бы на `$.each`

Comment: @teran так слишком просто :-)

Comment: @teran нужно больше жыквери